# SQL add Datetime add hour add Minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, addition, hour

In my table I have `DateTime`, `Hour` column.

example : `2012-05-14 00:00:00.000` and `1230`

How can I add this `hour` column into my `Datetime` column, so I can have

```
2012-05-14 12:30:00.000
```

I tried with this:

```
SELECT DATE_DEBUT, HEURE_DEBUT, 
   DATEADD(hour, CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 0, 2)), DATE_DEBUT) AS DateTemp, 
   DATEADD(hour, CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 2, 2)), DateTemp) AS DateComplete
FROM ESPTEMPS_PROGRAMMATION
```

but it does not work.

thanks you in advance,
Stev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to add the first two digits as hour, the second two as minute - but you're not doing this in your `DATEADD` calls - you're adding both parts as `HOUR` - try this instead:

```
SELECT DATE_DEBUT, HEURE_DEBUT, 
   DATEADD(MINUTE, CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 3, 2)), 
              DATEADD(HOUR, CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(HEURE_DEBUT, 1, 2)), DATE_DEBUT))
FROM ESPTEMPS_PROGRAMMATION
```

Here I'm using two nested `DATEADD` - the inner `DATEADD` adds the hours, the outer adds the minutes onto the result of adding the hours.

Also: `SUBSTRING` in SQL Server is **1-based**, e.g. the first character of a string is at position 1 (not 0, as you seem to assume)