# Concatenate date and string to create datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime2

I need to concatenate a datetime and a time field in SQL to a single date time.

e.g I have a datetime of 2017-09-05 00:00:00.000 and a string time of 11:00. What I want is a single field in a view of 2017-09-05 11:00:00.000

I have tried casting the datetime to a date and then concatenate the new date and string date field together but this doesn't work.

To cast the datetime I am using: `CAST(dtDate AS DATE) AS dtNewDate` which works fine. When I then use: `CAST(dtNewDate + szTime AS datetime) AS dtNewDateTime` the creation of the view works fine but selecting the top 1000 returns a "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Is there an easier way to do this or can anyone offer some advise (other than storing the date and time in a single datetime field in the first place as it is populated by a third party application which I do not have access to change)

Comment: how does 7 hours looks like, 07:00 or 7:00 ?

Comment: 7 hours is displayed as 07:00 in the string field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL add Datetime add hour add Minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020744/sql-add-datetime-add-hour-add-minute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `11:00` stands for `11:00:00`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT dtDate + CONVERT(DateTime, szTime, 108)
FROM...
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/HSCL82574)

Answer (score 2):

You can add two `datetime` values together, so try:

```
CAST(dtDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST(szTime AS TIME) as DATETIME)
```

Comment: You can leave out the `TIME` cast -- `11:00` will convert directly to a `DATETIME` (to wit, `1900-01-01 11:00`). Even so, this trick does not work for `DATETIME2`, which is unfortunate if you need the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.

```
DECLARE @YourDate AS DATETIME
SET @YourDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2017-09-05 00:00:00.000', 111) + ' 11:00'
PRINT @YourDate
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to get the hour from your stringfield, convert it to int, and add that as hours to the datetime

```
declare @date datetime = '20170905'
declare @stringtime varchar(5) = '11:00'

select left(@stringtime, 2),
       dateadd(hour, convert(int, left(@stringtime, 2)), @date)
```

If you also need the minutes you can do it like this :

```
declare @date datetime = '20170905'
declare @stringtime varchar(5) = '11:05'

select left(@stringtime, 2),
       right(@stringtime, 2),
       dateadd(minute, convert(int, right(@stringtime, 2)), dateadd(hour, convert(int, left(@stringtime, 2)), @date))
```

**This will only work if the stringfield is always in format hh:mm**

Comment: what about seconds and fractional seconds?

Comment: @Jodrell I did not cover that because they are also not in the question. The OP stated the time is in hh:mm format. I even asked this in a comment

Comment: @Jodrell And I also mention in bold text that this will only work when the time is in hh:mm format

Answer (score 0):

If you care about [precision with `DATETIME2`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server),

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME = '2017-01-01';

DECLARE @T varchar(7) = '11:00';

SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', @D), CAST(CAST(@T AS TIME) AS DATETIME2(7)));
```

[Running example here](http://rextester.com/HSCL82574)